# Uniform convergence preserved under composition with continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $M$ be a compact metric space, $V, W$ be Banach spaces, and $\alpha, \alpha_n : M \rightarrow V$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, be a sequence of continuous functions such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\alpha_n=\alpha$ uniformly on $M$.

Let further $\Psi : V \rightarrow W$ be continuous.

**Question:** Can we conclude that $\Psi\circ\alpha_n \rightarrow \Psi\circ\alpha$ *uniformly* on $M$ (as $n\rightarrow\infty$) even if $V$ is not necessarily compact?

(This is not a homework question.)

Comment: I doubt it, I'm pretty sure you need $\psi$ to be uniformly continous, or continous from a compact space to a complete space.

Comment: That's what I think too. Asked that just to be sure that I didn't miss anything.

Comment: "Yes" (even without compactness of $M$), and the proof is little more than expanding the definitions, which is a good exercise. :)

Comment: Oh wow, really? I'll give it a shot then, thanks @AndrewD.Hwang !

Comment: My whoops ... we do need _uniform_ continuity of $\Psi$, which we get from compactness. But that aside ....

Comment: Yes, that case is clear, though that's a big aside though :D

Comment: Without uniform continuity of $\Psi$ we're sunk, as Davide notes: Think of $f_{k}(x) = x + (1/k)$ and $\Psi(x) = x^2$ on the real line. :)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, though yours doesn't seem to be a counterexample to the given situation since $\Psi(f_k(x))$ still converges uniformly if the domain of $f_k$ is a compact subset (of the real line)?

Comment: You won't find counterexamples if $V$ is finite-dimensional. The sequence $(\alpha_n)$ is uniformly bounded and thus the union of their ranges is relatively compact. As $\Psi$ is uniformly continuous on compact sets, you always get uniform convergence. This is no longer true if $V$ is infinite-dimensional since bounded sets don't need to be relatively compact.

Comment: My earlier comments are misguided, based on my conflating the hypotheses of the question and the comments. I won't delete them, but please disregard, and apologies if they caused you to spend time looking for an "easy exercise" proof that doesn't exist.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang. Please see my A.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: IIRC, I got it into my head that $\Psi$ was _assumed_ to be uniformly continuous. <> (+1) for your answer, though I'm not yet wholly convinced about (3): Along the lines of MaoWao's comment, $N$ is shown to be complete, but in a general metric space we also need _totally_ bounded for compactness. (In a finite-dim'l Banach space, bounded implies totally bounded.) Does that concern seem substantive?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang .It is straightforward to show that $\overline N$ is sequentially compact, which is equivalent in a metric space to compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally let $V,W$ be metric spaces.

Notation: For any function $f$ and for any $T\subseteq dom(f)$ we write $f[T]=\{f(t): t\in T\}.$

Let $N=\cup_{n\in\Bbb N}\alpha_n[M].$

Let $S=(\,\alpha_{j(n)}(x_n)\,)_n$ be any sequence in $N.$ Let $(x_{i(n)})_n$ be a convergent sub-sequence of $(x_n)_n$ with limit $x\in M.$

(1). If for some $k$ we have $j(i(n))=k$ for infinitely many $n,$ then $(\,\alpha_{j(i(n))}(x_n)\,)_{[j(i(n)])=k]},$ that is, $(\,\alpha_k(x_{i(n)}\,)_{[j(i(n))=k]}$ is a subsequence of $S$ converging to $\alpha_k(x)\in N.$

(2). If $\{n: j(i(n))=k\}$ is finite for every $k,$ then we can find a subsequence $(i'(n))_n$ of the sequence $(i(n))_n$ such that $(\,j(i'(n))\,)_n$ is strictly increasing.

$(\bullet)$ The uniform convergence of $(\alpha_{j(i'(n))})_n$ to $\alpha$ then implies that $(\,\alpha_{j(i'(n))}(x_{i'(n)})\,)_n$ is a subsequence of $S$ converging to $\alpha(x).$ [Exercise for the reader.]

(3). From (1) and (2), every sequence in $N$ has a convergent subsequence, so $\overline N$ is compact.

(4). In the main Q we can replace $\Psi$ with its restriction $\Psi|_{\overline N}=^{def}F$ to the compact domain $\overline N.$ Now $F:\overline N\to W$ is uniformly continuous as both its domain and its image $F[\overline N]$ are compact. I leave it to the reader to show this implies  that $(F\circ \alpha_n)_n$ converges uniformly to $F\circ \alpha.$

Hint for $(\bullet):$ I suggest a proof by contradiction, using the fact that $\alpha$ is continuous because it is a uniform limit of a sequence of
continuous functions